# Django: reverse accessors for foreign keys clashing

Tags: python, django

I have two Django models which inherit from a base class:

```
- Request
    - Inquiry
    - Analysis
```

Request has two foreign keys to the built-in User model.

```
create_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='requests_created')
assign_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='requests_assigned')
```

For some reason I'm getting the error

`Reverse accessor for 'Analysis.assign_user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Inquiry.assign_user'.`

Everything I've read says that setting the `related_name` should prevent the clash, but I'm still getting the same error. Can anyone think of why this would be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your model definitions, including `Inquiry` and `Analysis` and their relationship to `Request`

Comment: [updated link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name) for related name in Django 1.9

Answer (score 220, accepted):

The `related_name` would ensure that the fields were not conflicting with each other, but you have two models, each of which has both of those fields. You need to put the name of the concrete model in each one, which you can do with some special [string substitution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name):

```
 create_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)s_requests_created')
```

Comment: @MatthewDrill I submitted an edit to correct it, in the meantime try https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name

Comment: Newer doc link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name