# Several properties with the same type Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models

```
class Manager(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Project(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
work_statement = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
contract_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
customer = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
#executer = models.ManyToManyField(Manager)
deadline = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

So there is logic
I want Model Project to has several managers as executers but not all of them how can i do it?

so for example:
Project "N" can include two managers for execution

i know that this way is not correct

```
class Project(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
work_statement = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
contract_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
customer = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
executer1 = models.ForeignKey(Manager)
executer2 = models.ForeignKey(Manager) 
deadline = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - using multiple foreign key to the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697771/django-using-multiple-foreign-key-to-the-same-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use manyToMany

Read the following documents

[djangoproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

[sankalpjonna](https://www.sankalpjonna.com/learn-django/the-right-way-to-use-a-manytomanyfield-in-django)